# Form parameters not passing but File in the same form processed?

Tags: java, forms, file, jsp, servlets

I have a webform on JSP which has several string values and a file to uploaded to the server through a servlet. It is strange to see that I'm able to upload the file on to the server but not able to get the values in the servlet using `request.getParameter("someString")`.

What's the problem with my code, or guide me?

**EDIT:** 
With a bit of research, i have come to know that if i use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag, i will not be able to get parameters in servlet using `request.getParameter()`. The question could be now, how can i send both a file and other values to a servlet for processing.

**webform.jsp**:

```
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/cassino/uploadFile" >
    <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >*ID riparazione</label>

                    <input type="text" name="idRiparazione"  />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>*ID mandrino smontato</label>

                    <input type="text" name="idMandrinoSmontato" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>*Service livello(SL)</label>
                <input type="text" name="serviceLivello" />
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Attachment</label>
                    <input type="file" name="attachment" class="" id="attach" />
                 </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <p class="text-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Salva"  name="newMacchina" /> 
            <input type="reset" value="Cancella" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

And **uploadFile.java**

```
@WebServlet( name = "uploadFile", urlPatterns = { "/uploadFile" } )
public class uploadFile extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int THRESHOLD_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 3;
    private static final int MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 15;
    private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 20;

    /**
     * handles file upload via HTTP POST method
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // checks if the request actually contains upload file
        //ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

        String idRiparazione = request.getParameter("idRiparazione");
        String idMandrinoSmontato = request.getParameter("idMandrinoSmontato");
        String serviceLivello = request.getParameter("serviceLivello");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println(idMandrinoSmontato);
        out.println(serviceLivello);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>"); 

        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);
        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

        // constructs the directory path to store upload file
        String uploadPath = "C:\\SKFSFCassino\\uploads\\riparazione\\";  //getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
        // creates the directory if it does not exist
        File uploaddir = new File(uploadPath);
        if( !uploaddir.exists()) {
            uploaddir.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator it = formItems.iterator();
            // iterates over form's fields
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) it.next();
                // processes only fields that are not form fields
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                    File storeFile = new File(filePath);
                    // saves the file on disk
                    item.write(storeFile);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/modules/SKFsfRepair/new/viewNewContent.jsp");

    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        throw new ServletException("GET method used with " + getClass().getName() + ": POST method required.");
    }
```

I don't think there could be a problem with the mapping but I am slightly confused about this too because my `web.xml` is not showing any mapping or servlet. The servlet would, however, upload the file and return the following output:

```
Hello Servlet Get

null null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that you can no longer use `request.getParameter()` in this situation with the multipart form.  [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html) provides access to your non-file form fields through the `FileItem` class.  As you iterate over the items, check the field names against the names you're looking for.

```
    ...
    String idRiparazione = null;
    String idMandrinoSmontato = null;
    String serviceLivello = null;

    try {
        List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator it = formItems.iterator();
        // iterates over form's fields
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) it.next();
            // processes only fields that are not form fields
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                File storeFile = new File(filePath);
                // saves the file on disk
                item.write(storeFile);
            }
            else
            {
                if ("idRiparazione".equals(item.getFieldName()))
                    idRiparazione = item.getString();
                else if ("idMandrinoSmontato".equals(item.getFieldName()))
                    idMandrinoSmontato = item.getString();
                else if ("serviceLivello".equals(item.getFieldName()))
                    serviceLivello = item.getString();
            }
        }

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println(idMandrinoSmontato);
        out.println(serviceLivello);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");             
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```